# Running an openquery in SQL Server with replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run this query in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(XREF_PROD,
               'select 
                    resourcecalenderid, 
                    racfid, 
                    leavetype, 
                    leavestartdate, 
                    leaveenddate, 
                    replace('modifiedby','^0-9a-zA-Z -', '') AS [CUSTOMER_MFG_VENDOR_NAME]
                    createdby, 
                    createdon, 
                    modifiedby, 
                    modifiedon 
                from XREF.XREF_RESOURCE_CALENDER')
```

Keeps telling a quote identifier is needed and I have tried different variations and can't get it to work...

I have tried running with double quotes also..

Thanks
fordraiders

Comment: Need a comma after `[CUSTOMER_MFG_VENDOR_NAME]`?

Comment: You can't use an expression in an `OPENQUERY` query; however, I'm not sure that's what you're after either. Looks like you haven't escaped your single quotes? When using a single quote (`'`) within a string literal, you need to escape it by putting the character twice. For example `SET @v = ''''` would set the value of `@v` to a single single quote (`'`).

Comment: OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "XREF_PROD" returned message "ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier".
Msg 7323, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while submitting the query text to OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "XREF_PROD".

Comment: SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
(
XREF_PROD,
'select 
resourcecalenderid, 
racfid, 
leavetype, 
leavestartdate, 
leaveenddate, 
REPLACE(REPLACE(modifiedby,''|'',''''),''\'', '''') modifiedby1,
createdby, 
createdon, 
modifiedby, 
modifiedon 
FROM XREF.XREF_RESOURCE_CALENDER'
 )       Thanks  , yes had to escape the single quote and the field comma..Thanks

Comment: @DavidPowell Do you realize that you are attempting to run a query against Oracle and that you must use syntax that is legal in that dialect? And now you have posted a very different query - which should be done as an update to your question and not as a comment. How is your new query relevant to the original question? This is called "adding confusion".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and replace Master with the name of the database example northwind
this is called a 4 part query used on linked servers.
4 parts LinkedServer.Database,Owner.Table

select resourcecalenderid, 
       racfid, 
       leavetype, 
       leavestartdate, 
       leaveenddate, 
       replace('modifiedby','^0-9a-zA-Z -', '') AS [CUSTOMER_MFG_VENDOR_NAME]
       createdby, 
       createdon, 
       modifiedby, 
       modifiedon 
from XREF_PROD.master.dbo.XREF_RESOURCE_CALENDER